# code is been executed twice coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I have a ColdFusion file that is scheduled in CF task to run every 30 seconds. The purpose of this file is to insert text from response table into order table. everything was working pretty cool before but now having issues i.e.

randomly 1 out of 6 times, the file is been executed twice with each line of code is running twice. so the order is inserted twice.

i have made a check that if same order with response id xxx exists dont insert it again. but still i am seeing duplicates. any help will be appreciated.

```
<cfquery name="getdupeordersinfile" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
        SELECT TOP 1 * from Orders
        Where ltrim(rtrim(smsresponseid)) = '#val(responseId)#'
    </cfquery>

    <cfif getdupeordersinfile.recordcount EQ 0>

        <cfquery name="getInsertInOrder" maxrows="1" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#" result="stResult">
            INSERT INTO Orders
               (....)
            values (...)

         </cfquery>


     </cfif>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'd wrap this block of CFQUERIES in <cftransaction> and see if that helps. Also, if you add a column restraint to disallow duplicate SMSResponseID, the second insert will fail regardless.

Comment: Are you sure it's running twice?  The http logs will help you determine that.  Also, if you need to run this every 30 seconds, have you considered using a database trigger instead of CF?

Comment: Given the limited information provided, there is no obvious reason the code would execute twice. You need to provide us with more context. For example, what is the actual code in your script (not just a snippet)? What is the source of `responseId`? Are there any cfc's involved? Also, post the logging results that confirm the code actually executes twice.

Answer (score 2):

I would use some variation of the following query that should work on any modern SQL database:

```
INSERT INTO Orders
    (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT  column1, column2, column3
FROM    Responses
WHERE   1 = 1
    AND ...
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Orders
            WHERE   ltrim(rtrim(smsresponseid)) = ltrim(rtrim(Responses.responseid))
        )
```

You could also use the same technique if you were entering static values not from a database.

```
INSERT INTO Orders
    (
        color,
        column1,
        column2
    )
SELECT  'red',
        <cfqueryparam value="#value1# ...>,
        <cfqueryparam value="#value2# ...>
WHERE   1 = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    Orders
            WHERE   ltrim(rtrim(smsresponseid)) = ltrim(rtrim(Responses.responseid))
        )
```

I am using "SELECT 1" instead of "SELECT TOP 1" because you don't need to fetch any fields at all. "SELECT 1" will just return the literal value of 1. This is useless, of course, but you didn't need a real value in an EXISTS clause anyway. Moreover, the database won't bother to retrieve more than one record in an EXISTS clause anyway.

[SQL Server: JOIN vs IN vs EXISTS - the logical difference](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx)

The article is specific to SQL Server, but my experience suggests this is true for most SQL databases.

EXISTS and NOT EXISTS are the best solutions for this sort of problem both because of the performance implications and because the syntax correctly and clearly describes exactly what you want.

**Why does this happen?**

As I failed to mention it before, here is why the code could be executing twice (just conjecture, but I have seen it).

Let's say this code is in order-response.cfm. Imagine that order-response.cfm gets called (by a user, by CFSCHEDULE, doesn't matter). Call this request #1. Immediately after this, it gets called again. Call this request #2.

In request #1, the check query runs and returns no records. Then (before the insert query gets completed in request #1), the check query gets run in request #2. Now, the check query in request #2 also returns no results. Then the insert query gets run in request #1. Then the insert query runs in request #2 (because the check query returned no results at the time it ran).

How close those requests have to be to each other to achieve this effect depends on the speed at which your code is running, which in turn depends (somewhat) on the load your server is under. If you have periods where the database server gets locked up (or the relevant tables get locked up), then you could have a bit of waiting for things to unlock, which could make these steps take a bit longer than you would expect.

Given that your task runs every 30 seconds, a slight slow-down in your database or ColdFusion could cause these requests to overlap, yielding this problem.

Putting it all in one SQL statements, makes the action somewhat atomic and much less likely to run into this (though it can still happen in rare circumstances).

I should have mentioned (as I think someone else already did) that you should add constraints to your table to reject duplicate entries on the off-chance that one should get through that level.

Comment: Thanks steve. But is there a reason on why the code will be executed twice.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

From the response table to the orders table you say.  My approach would resemble this:

```
insert into orders
(field1, field2, etc)
select field1, field2, etc
from response
where whatever
and somefield in
(select somefield 
from response
where -- here you specify the same conditions of the outer query
except
select somefield
from orders
)
```

The exact syntax will depend on your rdbms.  Some use the word minus instead of except, and others don't support this syntax at all.